# Is there a way to search a file, replace some text inside the file and only save the edited text

Tags: powershell, replace

I want to make my own little en- and decryption tool. I already have the encryption script and the 'Database', i now only need the decryption tool. Now there comes the PowerShell Script. I have multiple Strings in a text file, where my encrypted password is saved in, the script should search the text file for those strings and replace them with the password, than just the edited text (decrypted password) need to be saved in another file. Is there a way to do this with PowerShell?

I tried `-replace` but then only one string is changed and the rest of the file is saved too

```
$1  = "abc"
(Get-Content Text.txt) | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace $1, "`na" } | Set-Content EditedText.txt

$2  = "def"
(Get-Content Text.txt) | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace $2, "`nb" } | Set-Content EditedText.txt
```

Comment: Your question is unclear, what do you want to *save*, the line which matched the pattern the matched pattern or the replacement ? Please take the [tour]and read [ask].

Comment: I have a text file, i want to search this text file for a specific string, i want to replace that string with "X" and than save just the replacement into another file

Comment: The replacement is `X` just save `X` and you're done ;-). To be serious: you are still unclear. [Edit] the question to contain additional information. **PLEASE take the [tour] and read [Ask]**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming this is what you want to do.

```
(Get-Content -Path Text.txt -Raw).Replace($1, "'na").Replace($2, "'nb") | Out-File EditedText.txt
```

the **-Raw** flag will return a string object instead of a string[] and the **.Replace(valueToReplace, newValue)** method is a part of the string class. Finally, the Out-File will output it to a new file. If you want to append it to an existing file use the **-Append** switch on the Out-File command. Otherwise, it will just overwrite the file if one exists.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that PowerShell never preserves the input file encoding and your use of `Out-File` without `-Encoding` will result in "Unicode" (UTF-16LE) files in Windows PowerShell, which may be undesired. `Set-Content` defaults to the active ANSI code page; `Set-Content` is generally the (slightly) more efficient choice for saving input that are already _strings_. (In PowerShell _Core_, the consistent default encoding is UTF-8 without BOM).

Comment: The .Replace sometimes skips a few replacements. The initial text was 'abcda' and the final text ist 'acda', is there a way to fix this.

Comment: @DasBoss I believe .Replace() is case sensitive. Is that the problem? It shouldn't skip anything though.

Comment: By the way, normally you don't want to have a password decryption mechanism. You would just encrypt the plain text each time and compare it to the saved encrypted password. Basically, password hashing is what we are talking about. Unless you have a reason to have the plain text password, I wouldn't even worry about decrypting it.

Comment: @PatrickMcvay The skipping i was worrying about is gone now, it was the encryption script, that was faulty, but not obviously.